# symfony choice options loaded from a table

Tags: forms, doctrine, widget, symfony1

i need some help with Symfony and Doctrine forms.

What i want is to add a choice widget to a form, and load that choice widget with data from the db.

I have this in Survey.class.php:

```
$this->widgetSchema['service'] = new sfWidgetFormChoice(array(
  'choices'  => TService::getServiceTypes(),
  'multiple' => true,
  'expanded' => false));
```

And this is TService.class.php

```
class TService extends BaseTService
{
  static public function getServiceTypes()
  {
    return Doctrine::getTable("TService")
       ->createQuery()
       ->select('description')
       ->execute();
  }
}
```

What i have got is a select with 2 choices, and that's good, but the options are '1' and '2', instead of the service's descriptions.

Sugestions?

Thank you guys

Answer (score 1):

You should use `sfWidgetFormDoctrineChoice` instead of manually fetching the options (it has a validator pair as well). However, you'll still have your current problem. The solution for that: implement the `__toString()` magic function for your TService objects.

Answer (score 0):

Read this [populating drop downs from the database](http://www.howitt.com/?p=411) hopefully even if it is not what you want it will help. It's S 1.4 and Doctrine based.

Answer (score 0):

i got a "manual" solution, but I'm sure there are better ways. I just changed the `TService::getServiceTypes` method

```
$table = Doctrine::getTable("TService")
   ->createQuery()
   ->select('description')
   ->execute();

$arrayServices = $table->toArray();
$descServices = array();
foreach ($arrayServices as $service){
    $descServices[] = $service['description'];
}

return $descServices;
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do `./symfony doctrine:build --all`, it will create sfWidgetFormDoctrineChoice automatically, if you have the right schema:

```
Survey:
  columns:
    tservice_id: { type: integer }
  relations:
    TService:
      class: TService
      local: tservice_id
      foreignAlias: Surveys

TService:
  columns:
    description: { type: string(100) }
```